# Anchor image issue in css

Tags: html, css

I have tried lot but did not find any solution so that that can be helpful for me. I have a menu which look like as below. The Menu has multiple menu item and each item is an anchor that consists of image, text and arrow.

**Problem**:

1. Image height will fit according to anchor height and every element
   of anchor must be middle.
2. Arrow would be down or right, every arrow will fit to right.

[image]

**HTML CODE:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span>
    <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/toys/blocks/abc_blocks.png" alt="" />ADMIN
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 1.5em;//do not fix.
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

<kbd>**[plunker](http://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/pjmPov)**</kbd>

Comment: tell what you actually wanna to do, you can use `text-alignment` or `right` in css

Comment: @saleemahmed, for down arrow need alignment, and for image need fit

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/toys/blocks/abc_blocks.png" alt="" /> ADMIN
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

a div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
}

img {
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The trick here is to use the `line-height` on anchor tag along with `vertical-align:middle` on the img.

Note that you cannot use `//` for commenting in CSS. Only `/*... */` is supported.

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/apptrench/pen/dYEzMp).